# How to get current location after a few seconds of turning on the GPS?

Tags: java, android, android-gps

It is OK when I open the GPS long times, I can get my current location, but when I turn off and then turn on the GPS, it returns null as the current location. I need to refresh or reinstall the app to make the current location work. Is it possible to get the location after a few seconds of turning on the GPS?

Here is my code:

```
client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

                return;
            }
            client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MapsActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                    if(location!= null){
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

I found out that I need to use requestsLoctionUpdates, but I cannot find any tutorial that explains me how to do it in the new version of android studio (Location : 11.8.0). Can anyone can tell me how to use this code?

Comment: you have to wait for the gps to callibrate and lock onto its sattelites

Comment: but before I refresh or reinstall the app, it will not get the location @SteelToe